# Pylint: Check if all called functions and variables exist before executing

Tags: python, pylint

I am currently working on a rather large python-project. The size makes it sometimes difficult to remember the exact function name and involved variables, or if attributes I am referring on one end exist in the involved class on the other end. Typically, these issues arise later during runtime by crashing the program, which makes it especially annoying if the program was already running for some time.
Of course, this problem could be solved by being more careful and cross-checking each time I am referring to functions or attributes, but are there other options (such as using pylint o.ä.) I could use instead? Ideally for checking the code before executing it, saving time afterwards.

Comment: There are tools to do this for you, but at the same time, python is a language for consenting adults

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pylint does that, a type checker (like mypy) also does that if you typed your code. An IDE with auto-completion like Pycharm would also help.

Comment: How could I use pylint for that? Auto-completion unfortunately fails for larger projects sometimes

Comment: You should analyse your project when having dependencies properly installed. (Check docs, all these tools are properly documented)